# Implementing transaction costs to portfolio returns

Tags: transaction-costs

I want to implement transaction costs to the betting against beta strategy. Have any of you guys a simple way to add this to the strategy? As I understand from a bit of reading, I need to calculate the turnover of each stock. How is this done?

Comment: IIRC Betting Against Beta adjusts the portfolio monthly. So you have to calculate how much stock is bought/sold at that time. Typically this is done by comparing the weight $w_i^{-}$ immediately before rebalancing and the weight $w_i$ after rebalancing for each stock i.

Comment: Okay, so the difference in weights on the last day of the month and first day of the next month tells me the amount that has been invested in each stock. I take this portion and multiply it with some kind of standard costs? Are there any articles stating optimal standardized costs?